# What is best way to get angularjs ng-repeat variable to a directive called withn the repeat

Tags: angularjs-directive

The situation I have is that I want to change a somewhat different  element depending on the precise type of the variable in the ng-repeat loop which is not known until runtime.  I had thought that the scope in effect would have the variable as an object but when I break in my directive it is not so.  If I make an isolate scope in my directive using "@val" for a ng-repeat variable named "val" thus does not work.  I tried without an isolated scope but again it was not present when the directive fired.  So what should be done in such a case?  I am sure I am not the first person that wanted to access an ng-repeat loop variable from a custom directive.

If I try something like  
then I get only the string "val" where val is actually a non string object within the loop. Is this some weird effect of when different things are evaluated?

Comment: Would you mind posting some of your code? Your question is hard to understand without anything concrete to look at

Comment: I am pretty sure it would not help for this as it is a general question.  The problem seems to be that the ng-repeat loop variable is evaluated some other time or not explicitly available within a directive called in the ng-repeat loop.   Which is the core of my question.  Should I be able to expect to get access to loop variable of a surrounding ng-repeat in my directive or not?  And if so how can it be accessed or passed?

Comment: There are many terms in the question that are vague, making the question very hard to understand. Sample code would be very helpful to clarify some of these things. Even better would be a small fiddle/plunker showing the issue. Reading this, I have a few questions: What do you mean by "precise type", "scope in effect", and "does not work"? What part of the directive do you break in? Most importantly, which variable from ng-repeat do you want in the directive?

Comment: I break in the sense that in

   <tr ng-repeat="val in values">
      <my-directive></my-directive>
   </tr>

Cannot see val whether I try an attribute, no new scope created, isolated scope binding an atribute defined as "val" in the html call to the directive and so on.  By examining the no new scope case val, which is an object btw, is not defined at the time the directive's link function is called.  So I am confused.

Comment: I have the same problem, here's [some example code](https://gist.github.com/notionparallax/67272450)
The `<p>` is able to see the `person` scope, but my directive isn't. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do should work just fine. Here is an example...

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/4269/

```
<div ng-repeat="val in values"> <my-directive val="{{val}}">{{val}}</my-directive>
```

You can see that the value from the repeater is easily binded into the child directive.

Since you didn't provide any code, its hard to see where you are going wrong, but it might have something to do with the fact that you are using a table in your html. There was a bug in Angular, which was fixed in 1.2.13, related to repeating over table elements, since browsers actually manipulate the DOM inside of tables on their own sometimes.

Please see [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459) bug report regarding that issue.

I would update to the latest version of Angular and try again. If you still can't get it working, try to avoid using an html table. You can easily fake a table by styling divs appropriately