# ng-repeat scope not available to a directive within it

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that is repeated by an ng-repeat.

```
<div ng-repeat="p in people">
  <p>{{p.name.first}}</p>
  <slider-box
    title-text="{{p.name.first}}"
    body-text="Some body text"
    img-src="{{p.photo}}"
    more-link="#"></slider-box>   
  </div>
</div>
```

If I put a `<p>{{p.name.first}}</p>` before the directive, the `p` shows off a first name, but the `slider-box` doesn't seem to have access to `p` and therefore comes up blank as there's no data being given to it.

It probably isn't an async issue, as there are boxes being created, so angular knows that there *is* something to `ng-repeat` , and the `<p>` is getting filled in.

I've made an [an example site](http://notionparallax.co.uk/sliderBoxes/#) here that shows an example of the directive with dummy data (just strings) and then the repeated ones are below that.

A very similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220840/what-is-best-way-to-get-angularjs-ng-repeat-variable-to-a-directive-called-withn) but no code examples were posted and the trail seems to have gone dead.

Comment: `$timeout` might be useful. You can wait for the interpolation to get complete before you access the <p>.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't make a difference. I don't think that it is a timing issue as the p tag *does* get rendered properly.

Comment: `$evalAsync`? I am not too sure.

Comment: could you put it in jsfiddle or plunker.co ? It would be much easier to show you the results than copy and paste and create a new one.

Comment: Can you show us how your directive was defined?

Comment: I debated the pros and cons of a plunk vs putting it on my server, it was late and I chose the dumb option! Anyway, 
[here it is](http://plnkr.co/edit/BXIdQnxzdjfs3wy4qDdw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the attributes into the scope directly in the directive declaration.

In your directive declaration, instead of just having `scope: {}` , have something like `scope:{ imgSrc:"@" }`. It will pass the value of the attribute directly inside the isolated scope of your directive.

Take a look at [this short tutorial](http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-isolate-scope-attribute-binding) for a better explanation.

Comment: That worked far more easily than I was expectign it to! [Here's the updated plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yyu1rA?p=preview).   
_"Isolate scope is one of those things where you can read the docs for days and have no clue what they're talking about. Then, someone shows it to you and you're like, "Oh, that was really easy.""_